# Function call is Repeating in node js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am new to node js. I have used the python call where data comes from. Since the process is a little complex so it taking time to execute and node js to receive a response. The code I mentioned here tried to wait for the function to complete, but the function is repeating the call from the start and goes repeating until the python function finished and to get a response.
So after completion of function

```
console.log("Image Conversation::")
await bot.say(dumy_msg);
await bot.beginDialog('classfication_done_');
```

These statements are repeating for two times.

How to resolve the issue?

```
convo1.ask('Post Your message', async(answer, convo1, bot,message) => {
  if(message.type=='file_share') {

  console.log("Image Conversation::")
  const botToken = bot.api.token;

  const destination_path = '/_classification/upload/' + message.files[0].name;
  console.log("URl :::",message.files[0].url_private)
  console.log('Testing file share' + message.files[0].name);

  const url = message.files[0].url_private;
  const opts = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + botToken,
    }
  };
  request(opts, function (err, res, body) {
   
    console.log('FILE RETRIEVE STATUS', res.statusCode);

  }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destination_path)); 

  const img = '/_classification/upload/' + message.files[0].name;


  spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

  const getResponse = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const process = spawn('python',["/_classification/tensorflow-image-detection-master/classify.py",img] );
    process.stdout.on('data', data => {
        resolve(data);
    });
    });
}
const response = await getResponse();
var dumy_msg = `${response}`;
await bot.say(dumy_msg);
     
     await bot.beginDialog('classfication_done_');
  }
  
  else{
    await bot.say(message,"Please provide jpeg file format, other files are not allowed");
    await bot.beginDialog('classfication_done_');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the callback function(`async () => {}`) itself has been called twice.

I don't know exactly what the role `convo1.ask` do, but make sure it's not in a sitution call a callback twice.

Comment: I tried by removing python  function and other code except  await 'bot.say("PlainText ");' inside convo1.ask. But now it was only called once correctly.